# Datepicker Angular Material - Filter does not apply correctly for saturdays in even weeknumber

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Datepicker does picks the current daynumber of the week and does not chose the target one. I want to allow picking the saturdays of the even weeknumbers.

```
dateFilter = (d: Date | null): boolean => {
    const day = (d || new Date()).getDay();

    return (day == 6) && (this.getWeekNumber((d || new Date())) % 2 == 0); 
    // 1 means monday, 0 means sunday, etc.
  };

  getWeekNumber(_date: Date): number {
    _date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    // Thursday in current week decides the year.
    _date.setDate(_date.getDate() + 3 - (_date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
    // January 4 is always in week 1.
    var week1 = new Date(_date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
    // Adjust to Thursday in week 1 and count number of weeks from date to week1.
    return 1 + Math.round(((_date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000
      - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <input #minmaxInput matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="minDate" [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter"
          placeholder="Datum zum Abholen der Bestellung" [(ngModel)]="order_date_for">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker" style="font-size: 25px;"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div align="end">
      <button mat-flat-button class="order" (click)="send_order()" [disabled]="disable_order()">Bestellen</button>
    </div>
```

[DatePicket Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Zq0.png)

[DatePicket Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGRTM.png)

Comment: just give the function a copy of  `d` like:
`this.getWeekNumber(new Date(d))`